# How can I measure the execution time of a terminal process?

Tags: command-line, performance

I'm trying to measure the execution time of a process that I call via the command line (i.e., I want to find out how long it takes to for the process to finish). Is there any command that I can add to the command calling the process that will achieve this?

Answer (score 303):

Add `time` before the command you want to measure. For example: `time ls`.

The output will look like:

```
real    0m0.606s
user    0m0.000s
sys     0m0.002s
```

Explanation on `real`, `user` and `sys` (from `man time`):

- `real`: Elapsed real (wall clock) time used by the process, in seconds.
- `user`: Total number of CPU-seconds that the process used directly (in user mode), in seconds.
- `sys`: Total number of CPU-seconds used by the system on behalf of the process (in kernel mode), in seconds.

Comment: @ninjalj, can you provide more information on what the `real`, `user`, and `sys` times are that this command returns?

Comment: @JacobVlijm This answer isn't that elaborate. :) You could edit in your comment and make it so.

Comment: Note that you may need `sudo apt-get install time` if you are using a shell where `time` is not a builtin.

Comment: Note that this is the output from Bash's `time` builtin, but `man time` would be about an executable (like `/usr/bin/time`, from the `time` package), and its output would look different. Also in Bash, you can run `help time` for help with the builtin.

Comment: Note that the process end does not mean all the work is finished.  A copy may take additional minutes after the "time" returns for  flushing system bufffers (therefor with unallocated sys time also).

Comment: OMG! It is integrated in MacOS zhs already

Comment: For some reason, `time echo foo` don't display the time. Is there a way to display the time independent of the command when using `time`?

Comment: fish shell users: `time` is a fish builtin. If you want the standard version on your system, use `command time ...`

Answer (score 64):

For a line-by-line delta measurement, try [gnomon](https://github.com/paypal/gnomon).

> It is a command line utility, a bit like moreutils's ts, to prepend timestamp information to the standard output of another command. Useful for long-running processes where you'd like a historical record of what's taking so long.
>
> Piping anything to gnomon will prepend a timestamp to each line, indicating how long that line was the last line in the buffer--that is, how long it took the next line to appear. By default, gnomon will display the seconds elapsed between each line, but that is configurable.

[image: gnomon demo]

Comment: This is pretty slick.

Comment: (typo in link, fortunately URL ok). You can install it with `sudo npm i gnomon -g` if you have `npm`. Not sure how well it does against "progress" lines using '\r' (staying on the same line): in that case I'd like it counting it all as one long line, not separate ones.

Comment: so we pipe it to gnomon ! thats it ?

Comment: It is deprecated now, is there any similar alternative now?

Answer (score 32):

You can use `time`:

```
time ls -R
```

Answer (score 11):

```
date +"%T" && cp -r ./file  /destination/folder/here && date +"%T"
```

Running this command in the terminal will give you the total time for coping a file

Comment: This will give you the start time and end time, not the duration.

Comment: This is a good answer, under some circumstances.  For example, the following `find` command -- without the `2>/dev/null` redirect -- gives *copious* `Permission denied` messages. However, adding `2>/dev/null` to that command breaks the `time` portion of that command.  The following provides a good compromise: `START="$(date +"%s")" && find 2>/dev/null / -path /mnt -prune -o -name "*libname-server-2.a*" -print; END="$(date +"%s")"; TIME="$((END - START))"; printf 'find command took %s sec\n' "$TIME"`, giving (e.g.) `/usr/lib/libname-server-2.a  find command took 3 sec
` as the sole output.

Comment: An addendum to my comment: of course, you can simply run `time sudo find / -path /mnt -prune -o -name "*libname-server-2.a*" -print` (i.e., as `sudo`) -- avoiding those numerous `Permission denied` warnings.

Answer (score 6):

Occasionally I find myself needing a stopwatch to count how long it takes for an action like my app booting, in which case many of the solutions here are not useful.

For this I like to use [sw](https://github.com/coryfklein/sw).

[image: sw]

## Install

```
wget -q -O - http://git.io/sinister | sh -s -- -u https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coryfklein/sw/master/sw
```

## Usage

```
sw
 - start a stopwatch from 0, save start time in ~/.sw
sw [-r|--resume]
 - start a stopwatch from the last saved start time (or current time if no last saved start time exists)
 - "-r" stands for --resume
```

Answer (score 3):

```
time -v command
```

`-v` gives more information

Comment: -v: command not found

Comment: @Gqqnbig were you using this command on Mac OS? If yes, you can `brew install gnu-time` and use the command `gtime` instead of `time`.

Comment: If you use bash as your shell, it will use it's inbuild time function. To use the `time` program you may use `/usr/bin/time -v COMMAND` or `command time -v COMMAND`. :)

Answer (score 3):

In zsh, the `time` command's output is slightly different.

To interpret the output:

```
time sleep 10
sleep 10  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 10.011 total
```

The last number gives the total time as though it were recorded with a real life stopwatch (what you want 99% of the time). The other values are explained [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/424160/290197).

Answer (score 0):

In [Nushell](https://www.nushell.sh/commands/docs/timeit.html), the command is `timeit` instead of `time`.

```
> timeit java -jar benchmark.jar concurrency
[program output]
3min 42sec 994ms 803µs 978ns
```

Answer (score -2):

1. Open bashrc file

   ```
   gedit ~\.bashrc
   ```
2. Find the following text:

   ```
   if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\] :\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
   ```
3. And replace with:

   ```
   if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
       PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u\[\033[00m\] [\d|\t]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
   ```
4. Restart terminal to check.

[image: Sample output in terminal]

Comment: This will show the time. It will neither build the difference to the last command, nor will it account for waiting to type and hit ENTER or typing the command.