# Measuring performance with shell

Tags: command-line, date, benchmarks

How to subtract time and show seconds or miliseconds?

1. `begin_time=$(date)`
2. run something to be (fast , simple and informal) check performance
3. `echo $(date) - $begin_time`

of course, it is not working, how to do it?

Comment: Why down-vote? please explain.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I measure the execution time of a terminal process?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53444/how-can-i-measure-the-execution-time-of-a-terminal-process)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because the question doesn't show any research effort, and the syntax of your code is wrong. See [ask] for more details.

Comment: Thanks @wjandrea, I edited correcting basic syntax error (not the program that is rong because it is a question about how to do correct)

Comment: Thanks @wjandrea about link that I not see before: it is not a duplicate (I was supposing to use shell programming) but I would never have asked the question (if had I seen it before), so can be "functionally duplicate".

Comment: Fair point. Speaking of the shell, you didn't mention which one you're using. you can add a tag for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash has a built in function for this called `time`. Just prepend it to any command and it will time how long the command takes to run. For more info, see `help time` :)

```
[user@sol ~]$ time sleep 2

real    0m2.002s
user    0m0.002s
sys 0m0.000s
```

zsh has a similar builtin also called `time`, though no help page for `help time`. Here is sample output:

```
[sol ~]$ time sleep 2
sleep 2  0.00s user 0.00s system 0% cpu 2.003 total
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the `time` builtin, there exists `/usr/bin/time`, which is often more useful.

```
walt@bat:~(0)$ /usr/bin/time sleep 2
0.00user 0.00system 0:02.04elapsed 0%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 1756maxresident)k
80inputs+0outputs (1major+73minor)pagefaults 0swaps
walt@bat:~(0)$ /usr/bin/time -v sleep 2
    Command being timed: "sleep 2"
    User time (seconds): 0.00
    System time (seconds): 0.00
    Percent of CPU this job got: 0%
    Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:02.00
    Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
    Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
    Average stack size (kbytes): 0
    Average total size (kbytes): 0
    Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 1828
    Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
    Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
    Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 73
    Voluntary context switches: 2
    Involuntary context switches: 0
    Swaps: 0
    File system inputs: 0
    File system outputs: 0
    Socket messages sent: 0
    Socket messages received: 0
    Signals delivered: 0
    Page size (bytes): 4096
    Exit status: 0
walt@bat:~(0)$
```

Or, if you really want to do it by hand, read `man date` and use `date +%s.%N` (%s = seconds since Epoch, %N = nanoseconds)

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the `bash` or `zsh` shell, and only need a resolution of seconds, then you can use their `SECONDS` shell variable. From `man bash`:

> ```
> SECONDS
>        Each  time  this  parameter is referenced, the number of seconds
>        since shell invocation is returned.  If a value is  assigned  to
>        SECONDS,  the  value  returned upon subsequent references is the
>        number of seconds since the assignment plus the value  assigned.
> ```

So, if you assign a value of zero before executing your command (or sequence of commands), the subtraction is done for you.

Ex.

```
$ SECONDS=0 && sleep 2 && echo $SECONDS
2
```

Interestingly, `ksh93` has a `SECONDS` timer, but it appears to provide millisecond resolution:

```
$ ksh
$ SECONDS=0 && sleep 2 && echo $SECONDS
2.002
```

(The Korn shell - which predates `bash` and `zsh` - is more generally able to handle non-integer shell arithmetic.)

Answer (score 1):

#### Fixing up your code

(assuming you're using Bash)

```bsh
begin_time=$(date +%s)  # Get seconds since Unix epoch.
sleep 2  # For example
echo $(($(date +%s) - begin_time)) seconds
```

This should output `2 seconds`.

(N.B. Normally you should quote all expansions, but these values are guaranteed to be integers.)

#### Problems with your code

```
begin_time= date
```

- For assigning the output of a command to a variable, the syntax is `variable=$(command)`. The way you wrote it, it will call `date` with `begin_time` as an environment variable - not at all what you want.
- `date`'s output is locale-specific. That's why I use Unix time instead.

```
echo date - $(begin_time)
```

- This isn't in an arithmetic context, so the minus sign is treated as a string instead of an operator. Use `$((expression))`.
- To get the output of a command (command substitution), use `$(command)`
- To get the value of a variable (parameter substitution), use `$variable` or `${variable}`.